# TexLive 2019 and Hoefler Text features

Tags: fonts, xetex, hoefler, texlive-2019

I just updated my system to use TexLive 2019 and, since the update, some of the features that were previously working for `Hoefler Text` don't seem to work any more.

I have problems with alternate glyphs, which may be down to my poor coding, but my biggest problem is with small caps. I now get the following error, and it resorts to standard case in the compiled PDF. This doesn't seem to be the case with other fonts that I've tried. I should note that I'm doing this in `XeLaTex`.

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape TU/HoeflerText(1)/m/sc undefined (Font)              
using TU/HoeflerText(1)/m/n instead on input line 6."
```

Are there any reasons why this would be failing now, when it had previously worked ok prior to the update? Is there an easy fix?

Comment: I can confirm that \textsc{something} fails for TrueType Hoefler Text, as well as 'Palatino', another TrueType Apple font. This is broken in TL2019, though works correctly in TL2017 and TL2018.

Comment: You might report this at `tex-live@tug.org` to see if anyone there has information.  (It hasn't been reported there yet, to the best of my knowledge.)

Comment: What happens if you do `\font\test="Arial/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
\test Abc` (replace `Arial/OT`  by your font name, probably `HoeflerText/OT` or something like that, you find it in the log). Do you then get small caps?

Comment: Yes! That seems to work

Comment: Does that command load the font differently in some way?

Comment: Are you on macOS and do `\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}`? I get the same warnings, in this case. It's even worse with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @egreg what do you mean with "worse"? If hoefler has the small caps in a different file then the normal `+scmp` can naturally not work, but there should be no real difference between xelatex and lualatex here.

Comment: @egreg yes, exactly. Sorry, should have explained my system situation better at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

I have no problem with an up-to-date TL2019 and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{HoeflerText-Roman.otf}[
  BoldFont = HoeflerText-Bold.otf,
  BoldFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = HoeflerText-BoldSC.otf},
  ItalicFont = HoeflerText-RegularItalic.otf,
  ItalicFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = HoeflerText-RegularItalicSC.otf},
  BoldItalicFont = HoeflerText-BoldItalic.otf,
  BoldItalicFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = HoeflerText-BoldItalicSC.otf},
  SmallCapsFont = HoeflerText-RomanSC.otf,
]
\begin{document}

foo \textsc{Weather}
\bfseries
foo \textsc{Weather}
\itshape
foo \textsc{Weather}
\mdseries
foo \textsc{Weather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is that new that the small caps are in their own font file?

Comment: I don't think the OTF is the version that's distributed with MacOS though - my system comes with a TTF version installed (which used to work), and no sign of an OTF file...

Comment: I have two Hoefler Fonts, the original "Hoefler Text.ttc" and the ones used in my example. And yes, they have own SC files. DonÄt know why...

Answer (score 2):

I see the same problem in Mactex 2020.04.07 (using TeX Live 2020). My error message is:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/HoeflerText(0)/m/sc' undefined
```

I do not know why your font is `HoeflerText(1)` and mine is `HoeflerText(0)`.

To get small caps working I added:

```latex
\DeclareFontShape{TU}{HoeflerText(0)}{m}{sc}%
       {<-> "Hoefler\space Text:Letter\space Case=Small\space Caps"}{}
```

to the preamble.

If you want small caps in bold, italic, and bold italic you should also add:

```latex
% Bold small caps
\DeclareFontShape{TU}{HoeflerText(0)}{b}{sc}%
       {<-> "Hoefler\space Text\space Black:Letter\space Case=Small\space Caps"}{}
% Italic small caps
\DeclareFontShape{TU}{HoeflerText(0)}{m}{scit}%
       {<-> "Hoefler\space Text\space Italic:Letter\space Case=Small\space Caps"}{}
% Bold italic small caps
\DeclareFontShape{TU}{HoeflerText(0)}{b}{scit}%
       {<-> "Hoefler\space Text\space Black\space Italic:Letter\space Case=Small\space Caps"}{}
```